# JOIN with WHERE from JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have multiple tables with data on some clients. What I want to achieve is to output the amount that a certain client was billed for, in the first month he was billed.

So I run the code similar to the one bellow:

```
SELECT company,clientid,COALESCE (signed.value,reactivated.value) as 'Activation' , Amount FROM `tblclients`
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues  as signed  ON tblclients.clientid = signed.relid and signed.fieldid = 5
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues  as reactivated ON tblclients.userid = reactivated.relid and reactivated.fieldid = 27
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT clientid,sum(total) as Amount FROM tblinvoices  
    WHERE month(invoicedate)=month(Activation) Group by clientid) as f on tblclients.clientid = f.clientid
```

My problem is that when I do the last join it gives an error : *Unknown column 'Activation' in 'where clause'*. 
If I switch that to current_date the rest of the query works.

### Any idea on how to make this work ?

Later edit: I might have oversimplified the query, I also have a COALESCE

Comment: You can't use the alias when joining. Try using your actual column name instead

Comment: You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses. Just replace `Activation` with it's definition i.e. `activated.value`

Comment: I also have a COALESCE so I cannot directly reference it. Since the 'Activation' column is from the join, i cannot directly reference it

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT company,clientid,activated.value as Activation , Amount 
FROM `tblclients`LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues as signed ON tblclients.clientid = signed.relid and signed.fieldid = 5
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT clientid,sum(total) as Amount 
  FROM tblinvoices Group by clientid
) as f on tblclients.clientid = f.clientid and month(invoicedate)=month(Activation)
```

Comment: same error but on the invoicedate field